# Deleting content in multiple sheets - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

sheetNo = 1

With Worksheets("Sheet" & sheetNo)
.Range("A1:B12").ClearContents
End With
sheetNo = sheetNo + 1

End Sub
```

Assume I have 10 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet 3,........) and when I click CommandButton2 it should delete whatever the content in the range A1:B12. But this code deletes the content only in the Sheet1. can someone tell me why and where have I gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How about enclosing the code in a `for` or a `while` loop?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Would you like to help me with an example? Thanks

Comment: I would urge you learn the language constructs first. Your question is simple for anyone to answer. However, that shouldn't stop you from looking beyond the answers (esp. for basic stuff).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [how to use loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317029/need-help-making-the-vba-excel-code-better/16317480#16317480)

these are just 3 simple loops examples ( all 3 are doing the same thing ) for you to better understand how loops work

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    ' using for each loop
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Range("A1:B12").ClearContents
    Next

    ' using for loop with an iterator
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Range("A1:B12").ClearContents
    Next i

    ' using do while loop
    i = 1
    Do While i <= Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Range("A1:B12").ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me multiple perspective to handle my issue. Appreciate much.